# New (?) math object. Looking for (if existing) literature

Tags: gr.group-theory, quantum-groups

I am interested in any literature about the following mathematical property.

Let $V$ a vector space and $G$ a group acting on $V$.

What is the name for the property of a set of operators $H=\{h:V\to V\}$ being stable under conjugation by $G$:

$$
gHg^{-1}=H,\;\;\; \forall  g\in G
$$

i.e. the action of each element of $G$ on $H$ is a permutation of the $H$ elements?

Does this property have a name? Has this property been studied, even for particular groups?

Thank you.

Fabio

Comment: do I understand this correctly? take as an example for $G$ the group of orthogonal matrices, then the operators $H$ are multiplication by a scalar.

Comment: It'd be called the "commutator" of (the image of) $G$ in operators on $V$. Yes, much-studied...

Comment: thanks carlo, why is that? what about other groups like SU(n) for example?

Comment: Thanks paul, can you point me out a easy paper on the topic?

Comment: "Define $H$ as the set of operators $H = \{h : V \to V, h \in H\}$ …"?  I'm having trouble decoding that definition, which sounds circular.  In $g H g^{-1} = H,\quad\forall g \in G$, do you mean $g h g^{-1} = h,\quad\forall g \in G, h \in H$?

Comment: Thanks LSpice, I corrected it, typo

Comment: I mean the set of operators $H$ with the property that for all $h\in H$  $ghg^{-1}=h',\;\;\exists h'\in H\;\; \forall g\in G$.

Comment: [That](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421399/new-math-object-looking-for-if-existing-literature#comment1082620_421399) condition is circular:  you can't test whether $g h g^{-1}$ belongs to $H$ until you've defined $H$, so you can't use that requirement in the definition of $H$.

Comment: I think Fabio is asking for a name for the *property* of a subset $H$ of linear endomorphism of $V$ being closed under conjugation by $G$.

Comment: Let me try again: H is a set the of operators that are mapped into themselves (modulo permutation) by  G-conjugation (G given). Why is the definition of H circular?

Comment: Yes Sam! thanks and some pointer in the literature.

Comment: @Fabio: sorry, can't help you with that. It's a natural thing to consider but I've never heard of any special name.

Comment: The definition is circular because, under the requirement $\forall h \in H\,\forall g \in G\,\exists h' \in H\,g h g^{-1} = h'$, you cannot look at an individual operator $h$ and tell whether or not it belongs to $H$; you need the whole  family $H$ first.  You could, as @‍paulgarrett [suggests](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1082615), require that $h' = h$; or you could, as @SamHopkins [suggests](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1082630), ask of a random $H \subseteq \operatorname{End}(V)$ whether it satisfies this property—but you cannot so *define* $H$.

Comment: Thanks Lspice and Sam. Lspice do you have in mind any pointer to help me getting an idea of H as a random a  H⊆End(V)? I have the feeling that even for simple groups it a difficult object to characterize.

Comment: @LSpice: I think this is just a language thing. It would be normal to say, informally, "Let $X$ be a set where you can add its elements and scale them; what is a name for $X$?" with the intended answer answer being "vector space."

Comment: @SamHopkins, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1082637), if the asker confirms that this is what they meant, then I am not here just to harp on such issues of language.  However, since [at least one user (other than I) was confused](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1082615), it seems worth it to be explicit; and the asker has not yet explicitly agreed to this interpretation, so I'm still not sure that it's what they meant (though I agree that it seems plausible, now that you've suggested it).

Comment: I would call this, "$H$ is normalized by $G$," but I think the thing causing the debates is that you can't say "the" group $H \le GL(V)$ normalized by $G$, but rather "a" group $H \le GL(V)$ normalized by $G$. For example $H=\{1\}$ is normalized by $G$, and $H=G$ is normalized by $G$, and $H=GL(V)$ is normalized by $G$, and probably various other choices of $H \le GL(V)$. So it's not like a given $G$ leads to a uniquely determined $H$.

Comment: As @LSpice said, the sentence "Define $H\ \dots$ in the question doesn't define $H$. The requirement $(\forall g\in G)\,gHg^{-1}=H$ is satisfied iff $H$ is the set of all operators on $V$. It's also satisfied if $H=G$. It's also satisfied if $H$ consists only of the identity operator. It's also satisfied if $H$ is empty.The "definition" fails to say unambiguously what $H$ is.

Comment: Sorry I am not a mathematician but  the way sam expressed my question is the way I do understand the problem. Is this something that people have studied? If not what are similar proprieties that I can start to look at that  people have already studied? A group ‘normalized’ by a set of operators? Thx

Comment: Notice that if $H$ has that property, so does its linear span. After this extension, you are basically looking at $G$-invariant subspaces of ${\rm End}(V)$.

Comment: Could anybody who understood the OP's intent edit the question so as to make correctly stated?